# Cannot understand SQLException exception in clojure

Tags: jdbc, clojure

I have created some clojure function to access a database, as shown in the snippet below:

```
(defn get-dg [date]
  (let [query (str "......")
        ]
    (jdbc/with-connection db
      (jdbc/with-query-results rows 
          [query date date date date]
          (.debug log rows)
          (if (not (seq rows)) 
           nil
           rows))))
)
```

Everything works fine. The query returns a result set which I can then process. Now, if I comment out (.debug log rows) I get this:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: Closed Resultset: next
```

Any idea why?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"rows" are lazy. And It's seems that "(.debug log rows)" evaluated the "rows". Just do it explicitly:

```
(defn get-dg [date]
  (let [query (str "......") ]
    (jdbc/with-connection db
      (jdbc/with-query-results rows [query date date date date]
        (comment .debug log rows)
        (if (empty? rows) nil (doall rows))))))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I suspected that lazy evaluation could be the reason. Apparently, (.debug) forced sequence evaluation.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure, but I guess that the problem is, that the result seq is lazy and by the time you process it the db connection is closed (you're outside the `with-connect`).

Your debug statement forces the realization while the connection is still open.

Some minor stylistic comments:

You don't have to use str to convert a string to a string.

The if not seq thing, can be simplified to:

```
(if (seq rows)
    rows)
```

(or even to just `rows`, if it can only be a seq or `nil` anyway)